# Fetch http in Flutter - factory constructor needs update after every currency change

Tags: flutter, dart, http, factory

I am new to flutter and working with http requests for the first time. I have no problem making the code work in the first instance since factory constructor fetches bitcoin price in USD: `json['RAW']['BTC']['USD']['PRICE']`.

The problem arises when i want to display the price in another currency like GBP or EUR. Because i need to change factory constructor to search for the changed string

as an example

- GBP - the body of api call changes to `json['RAW']['BTC']['GBP']['PRICE']`
- EUR - body changes to `json['RAW']['BTC']['EUR']['PRICE']`

My question is how can I make this ['currency'] change when I assign a currency in my dropdownbutton-list?

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'price_screen.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
          primaryColor: Colors.lightBlue,
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white),
      home: const PriceScreen(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}
```

price_screen.dart

```
import 'dart:io' show Platform;
import 'package:bitcoin_ticker_flutter/coin_data.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class PriceScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const PriceScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<PriceScreen> createState() => _PriceScreenState();
}

class _PriceScreenState extends State<PriceScreen> {
  String selectedCurrency = "USD";

  DropdownButton<String> androidDropdown() {
    List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> dropdownItems = [];
    for (String currency in currenciesList) {
      var newItem = DropdownMenuItem(
        value: currency,
        child: Text(currency),
      );
      dropdownItems.add(newItem);
    }

    return DropdownButton<String>(
      value: selectedCurrency,
      items: dropdownItems,
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(
          () {
            selectedCurrency = value!;
            getData();
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  CupertinoPicker iOSPicker() {
    List<Text> pickerItems = [];
    //List<PickerItem<String>> PickerItems = [];
    for (String currency in currenciesList) {
      pickerItems.add(Text(currency));
    }

    return CupertinoPicker(
      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
      itemExtent: 32.0,
      onSelectedItemChanged: (selectedIndex) {
        print(selectedIndex);
      },
      children: pickerItems,
    );
  }

  String coinValue = '?';

  void getData() async {
    try {
      var data = await CoinData().fetchCoin(selectedCurrency);
      setState(() {
        coinValue = data as String;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  late Future<Coin> futureCoin;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureCoin = CoinData().fetchCoin(selectedCurrency);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text(' Coin Ticker'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18.0, 18.0, 18.0, 0),
            child: Card(
              color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
              elevation: 5.0,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    vertical: 15.0, horizontal: 28.0),
                child: FutureBuilder<Coin>(
                  future: futureCoin,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      return Text(
                        '1 BTC ${snapshot.data!.price.toStringAsFixed(0)} $selectedCurrency',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      );
                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Text('${snapshot.error}');
                    }

                    // By default, show a loading spinner.
                    return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 150.0,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30.0),
            color: Colors.lightBlue,
            child: Platform.isIOS ? iOSPicker() : androidDropdown(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

coin_data.dart

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'price_screen.dart';

const List<String> currenciesList = [
  'AUD',
  'BRL',
  'CAD',
  'CNY',
  'EUR',
  'GBP',
  'HKD',
  'IDR',
  'ILS',
  'INR',
  'JPY',
  'MXN',
  'NOK',
  'NZD',
  'PLN',
  'RON',
  'RUB',
  'SEK',
  'SGD',
  'USD',
  'ZAR'
];

const List<String> cryptoList = [
  'BTC',
  'ETH',
  'LTC',
];

const apiKey =
    "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
const coinDataURL =
    "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=BTC&tsyms=";

class CoinData {
  Future<Coin> fetchCoin(selectedCurrency) async {
    final response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse('$coinDataURL$selectedCurrency&$apiKey'));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
      // then parse the JSON.
      return Coin.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    } else {
      // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
      // then throw an exception.
      throw Exception('Failed to load album');
    }
  }
}

class Coin {
  final double price;

  const Coin({
    required this.price,
  });

  factory Coin.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Coin(
      price: json['RAW']['BTC']['USD']['PRICE'],
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried to make the part of ['currency'] change according to my changes in the dropdown menu of listed currencies.

but so far i have been unable to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have make one small changes in your function of COIN_DATA.dart file

Your one is as below

```
class CoinData {
  Future<Coin> fetchCoin(selectedCurrency) async {
    final response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse('$coinDataURL$selectedCurrency&$apiKey'));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
      // then parse the JSON.
      return Coin.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    } else {
      // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
      // then throw an exception.
      throw Exception('Failed to load album');
    }
  }
}

class Coin {
  final double price;

  const Coin({
    required this.price,
  });

  factory Coin.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Coin(
      price: json['RAW']['BTC']['USD']['PRICE'],
    );
  }
}
```

Change to below one:

```
class CoinData {
  Future<Coin> fetchCoin(selectedCurrency) async {
    final response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse('$coinDataURL$selectedCurrency&$apiKey'));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
      // then parse the JSON.
      return Coin.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body),selectedCurrency);
    } else {
      // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
      // then throw an exception.
      throw Exception('Failed to load album');
    }
  }
}

class Coin {
  final double price;

  const Coin({
    required this.price,
  });

  factory Coin.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json,String selectedCurrency) {
    return Coin(
      price: json['RAW']['BTC'][selectedCurrency]['PRICE'],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. After choosing another currency in the dropdown menu I get the following error -

I/flutter (26718): type 'Coin' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast. Price does not get updated according to currency

How do I solve that?

Comment: Please contact me via email:  methaniyagautam@gmail.com.